# How to center text in destination in flutter navigation rail?

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

I'm trying to create navigation like the below Image using a navigation rail to get the solution
[image: The result I'm trying to get]

But I'm unable to center the text like in the image. The paper sheets category is not in the center. How do I get the formatted center text in the first image I have posted.

[image: result i'm getting]

```
@override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return SafeArea(
      child: Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
          backgroundColor: AppColors.blue,
          title: Text(subCategory.categoryTitle!),
        ),
        body: Row(children: [
          LayoutBuilder(builder: (context, constraint) {
            return SingleChildScrollView(
              child: ConstrainedBox(
                constraints: BoxConstraints(minHeight: constraint.maxHeight),
                child: IntrinsicHeight(
                    child: SizedBox(
                      width: 80,
                      child: NavigationRail(
                  labelType: NavigationRailLabelType.all,
                  destinations: <NavigationRailDestination>[
                      for (var i = 0; i < subCategory.subCategory!.length; i++)
                        NavigationRailDestination(
                          icon: Icon(Icons.shop),
                          // selectedIcon: Icon(Icons.favorite),
                          label: Center(
                            child: Text(
                              subCategory.subCategory![i].subCategoryName!,
                              style: TextStyle(color: Colors.black),
                            ),
                          ),
                        ),
                  ],
                  selectedIndex: selected,
                  onDestinationSelected: (value) {
                      setState(() {
                        selected = value;
                      });
                  },
                ),
                    )),
              ),
            );
          }),
        ]),
      ),
    );
```

Comment: Wrap the `Text` widget with either `Expanded` or `Flexible` widget.

Comment: Set textAlign:TextAlign.center in you text widget

Comment: If textAlign doesn't works put the text in Column and set crossAxisAlignment:CrossAxisAlignment.centre

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use  `textAlign: TextAlign.center,` on lavbel Text.

```dart
label: Text(
  "${subCategory.subCategory?[i].subCategoryName}", //null acceptation
  textAlign: TextAlign.center, //this
  style: TextStyle(color: Colors.black),
),
```